# 2011 Hyosung GT250R - Stalls and Stutters at Lights

Tags: motorcycle, stall, hyosung

I have owned a 2011 EFI Hyosung GT250R for about a month.  I haven't had any problems.

Today, I was riding in 2nd gear and I shifted down to 1st to make a quick stop, and once stopped the idle speed dropped about 200RPM's. When I went to take off, it stalled, and would not start and run for about 15 minutes.

I am taking it to a shop tomorrow for something else but what is going on with the idle and throttle response problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Water in the gas?

Comment: @oliverwilson    have you had any luck identifying the problem?  If so, please respond with an answer to your own question.  Would like to know what the resolution was.

Comment: Are you still having this issue?